# why does the following assembly code crash?

Tags: pointers, assembly, crash

i'm a comp sci student learning assembly at school.
 I was browsing through some of the questions in the book, and I saw a question asking why does the following code crash?

```
/*
gcc -o crashCity.exe crashCity.s
*/
.text
    .global _main
_main:  
    nop
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    addl $4, %ebp
    movl $0, %eax
    movl %ebp, %esp 
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

I understand that the line that causes the program to crash is `addl $4, %ebp` since it sets the base pointer four bytes up the stack, and since we're setting the stack pointer to the base pointer it will also make the stack pointer go up the stack by 4 bytes. however I still don't understand why will this make the program crash?
at first i thought it was because of the return statment, since `ret` will take what ever value pointed to by the stack pointer and move it to the instruction pointer. but then after I deleted the `add $4, %ebp` line, I deleted the `ret` statment and everything worked fine (meaning`ret` was not even neccessary. 
so what is causing the program to crash?
I'm using MINGW 32 bit windows GAS compiler.
any help is appreciated
thanks!!

Comment: different assembly language has different convention + syntax. Would be better to specify which language is that

Comment: Your explanation is correct. As to why it doesn't crash if you remove the `ret` ... you were just lucky.